# Monitor resolution can't be saved

Tags: resolution

Today I installed Lubuntu 13.10 on Vmware Player (inside Windows).

I change the Monitor setting (resolution) from default 800x600 to 1680x1050. It works. Beside Apply, I also press Save button. "Changes are saved" appears.
But - after restart, the resolution is again in 800x600.

I also opened /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart and add (it was empty before) one line:
@xrandr --mode 1680x1050

After restart the default resolution is back again.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu > Preferences > Default Applications for LXSessions. Select "Autostart" and put this command line in "Manual autostarted applications"

```
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1680x1050
```

Virtual1 = output name in monitor config.

Example:

[image]